# App for managing my app?

Tags: ios, swift, content-management-system

I'm releasing my first large app soon, and I've been thinking of writing a small app to manage the databases for my own app with master privileges, to clean up data and the like. This will just be a dev project shared with a few people within the company.

Is this something that people do?
Has anyone had any experience with this?

It feels like a good idea, but I'd also really love feedback.

Comment: Off topic question. But who cares what other people do, even though enterprise apps are a thing, do what works for you and your team. There's no right answer, just opinions, ergo off topic.

Comment: Fair enough, I've been trying to see they're best practices, or major fallbacks to this approach, but you're right. This is a large question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say database you are not referring to coredata specifically but rather some remote database. There is certainly nothing wrong with you creating tools to help you do your job.

I think really this answer is going to come down to time management. If your database has complicated relationships,etc that a simple database editor is not going to be able to maintain or will be highly prone to human error mistakes, I'd say go for it. But, if you are just making trivial changes it might be a more efficient use of time to use a existing solution.